# sqlalchemy-continuum with Automap Base

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-continuum

I am trying to integrate SqlAlchemy with SQLAlchemy-continuum.
I use Automap feature instead of making declarative classes, I have been unable to use continuum with the automap feature. Also there are no examples or citations in the docs regarding the same.

Has anybody used SqlAlchemy-continuum with this feature.

Note - I am using custom schemas for postrgesql, the schema is not the default the postrges ships with.

Also adding some code for reference:

```
#Imports

from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy_continuum import make_versioned
from sqlalchemy_continuum import version_class, parent_class

make_versioned(user_cls=None) #Currently trying to not make user relationship with transactions table.

#Created the engine and queried the schema metadata from there in _metdadata.

_metdadata.reflect(views=True)
Base = automap_base(metadata=_metdadata)

class Map1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_pg_audit'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': 'True'}
    __versioned__ = {}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


Base.prepare()

rec = TestPGAudit(name='test')
dbsession.add(rec)
dbsession.flush()
dbsession.commit()

#The History Class is not found, and sqlalchemy_continuum.exc.ClassNotVersioned is raise here.
at = version_class(TestPGAudit)

recs = dbsession.query(at).all()
print recs
```

I have also tried configuring the mappers at different places including after Base.prepare, but to no avail.
Also tried creating history tables in database manually.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _sqlalchemy_continuum.exc.ClassNotVersioned is raise here_ -> can you [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback(s)?  _I have been unable to use continuum with the automap feature_ is rather vague as a problem description.